# context.contentWrapper.getpackageName Null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

For many hours i got fed-up while resolving one error. When I start the intent the program crash and give the

context.contentWrapper.getpackageName Null pointer exception

Here is my Main activity

```
public class SelectCategory extends Activity {
    private static Context context1;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private View v3;
    public static ArrayList<Bitmap> imageArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    private static ArrayList<String> priceArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private MoverAdapter mover;







    private GridView gridView;


    public SelectCategory(Context context, ViewFlipper viewFlipper) {
        context1=context;

        inflater=(LayoutInflater)context1.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v3=(inflater.inflate(R.layout.category,null));
        viewFlipper.addView(v3);

        gridView=(GridView)v3.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        gridView.setAdapter(new MoverAdapter(context1));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i = new Intent(SelectCategory.this, description_class.class);
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);

            //  Toast.makeText(context1, "YEs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
```

Here is adapter

```
public static class MoverAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
    //  public ArrayList<Bitmap> imageArray;

        public MoverAdapter(Context c ) {

            context = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return imageArray.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context1.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_adapter, null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_img);
            TextView p_Price = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_size);
            //CheckBox c_box =(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            p_Price.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageArray.get(position));
            //c_box.setId(position);

            if(priceArray.get(position)!=null)
                p_Price.setText(priceArray.get(position));




            return v;

        }
    }
```

And here is the activity to start

```
public class description_class extends Activity {

        //private Context context;
        //private ArrayList<Bitmap> imageArray;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.catogory_description);



            Intent i = getIntent();

            int pos = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

            //MoverAdapter mover_adapter = new MoverAdapter(getApplicationContext());


            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageArray.get(pos));

    }
    }
```

This is my Menifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mooremachine"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mooremachine.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.mooremachine.description_class">


        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You cannot have a constructor for your activity. You just declare the activity in manifest and android does the job of launching the activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Replace the constructor in `MainActivity` with this code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category);

        gridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        gridView.setAdapter(new MoverAdapter(this));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i = new Intent(SelectCategory.this, description_class.class);
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);

            //  Toast.makeText(context1, "YEs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
```

In `Manifest.xml`, declare the second activity inside `Application` tag.

```
<activity
   android:name=".description_class"
   android:label="Description Activity"
   />
```

Comment: Hello thanks for Reply. Actually I am using constructor parametor to another class which is here bellow so suggest me is this right way to remove the construcotr


  ViewFlipper02 = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper02);
  
  
 
  
  
  
  
  //mail_class=new MailClass(MainActivity.this, ViewFlipper02);
  select_category=new SelectCategory(MainActivity.this, ViewFlipper02);
  //category_two=new Category_two(MainActivity.this, ViewFlipper02);
  
  ViewFlipper02.setDisplayedChild(0);
  select_category.setFolder("category3");


    }

Comment: You have simply commented the initialization which is not correct. What I mean to say is you should not write constructor inside any activity at all. I found a tutorial explaining about `ViewFlipper`. Check [this](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-viewflipper-example.html) out.

Comment: Yeah this is fixed by replacing this code 

    Intent i = new Intent(SelectCategory.this, description_class.class);
                    i.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(i);

Replaced to

    Intent i = new Intent(context1, description_class.class);
                    i.putExtra("id", position);
                    context1.startActivity(i);